# c# visual studio using settings.settings for mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using settings.settings in visual studio 2017. I checked settings.settings and my connection string is there and is set properly (as a connection string and is complete). I looked everywhere and tried a bunch of different code to get it to work but it's simply not working. I've been at this for way too many hours so your help would be greatly appreciated. If you could post the code you would use it would be great. I am using the MySql.Data.MySqlClient and System.Configuration. I can connect by inserting the connection string manually but I really want to use the settings since I will need to change this info once the system is installed on location and don’t want to change the code on all the forms once there.

Here is my code:

```
public dbadmin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection ok");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connectionstring requested via `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"]` gets retrieved from the `App.config`file instead of `Settings.settings`.

If you want to keep using  `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"]` you have to add the connectionstring to `App.config` as shown below.
*(Provide your values for `connectionString`and `providerName`.)*

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="shopmanagerConnectionString1" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That worked. I had an extra line of code in App.config for some odd reason. Removed it to match the given answer and all is good!